# Dúvida Iniciante - Erro no Loop

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

Galera, estou fazendo um exercício, porém algo está dando conflito neste pequeno trecho da repetição, da para colocar as primeiras informações do primeiro Loop, porém quando passa para o segundo em diante, ele pula a parte do Nome. Já inverti a ordem e não tenho ideias de como resolver.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

/* Escrever um algoritmo para um programa que leia um conjunto de 50 fichas contendo cada uma, o nome, 
altura e o sexo de uma pessoa. Calcule e imprima :
a) A maior e a menor altura da turma b) A media de altura das mulheres c) A média de altura da turma */

```
double somaT = 0, mediaM = 0, mediaT = 0, altura, somaM = 0;
double maiorH = 0, menorH = 999, maiorM = 0, menorM = 999;
char nome[30], sexo;                    
int i, mulher, turma;
turma = 0;
mulher = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    printf ("Digite seu nome: ");
    gets (nome);
    printf ("Digite seu sexo: ");
    sexo = getche();
    printf ("\nDigite sua altura: ");
    scanf ("%lf", &altura);

    if (sexo = 'm') {
            if (altura > maiorH) {
                maiorH = altura;
            }
            if (altura < menorH) {
                menorH = altura;
            }
    }
    if (sexo = 'f') {
        mulher++;
        somaM = somaM + altura;
            if (altura > maiorM) {
                    maiorM = altura;
                }
                if (altura < menorM) {
                    menorM = altura;
                }
    }
    turma++;
    somaT = somaT + altura;
}
mediaM = somaM / mulher;
mediaT = somaT / turma;

if (maiorH > maiorM) {
    printf ("A maior altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", maiorH);
}
else {
    printf ("A maior altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", maiorM);
}
if (menorH < menorM) {
    printf ("A menor altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", menorH);
}
else {
    printf ("A menor altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", menorM);
}

printf ("A media de altura das mulheres eh: %.2lf \n", mediaM);
printf ("A media de altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", mediaT);

system ("PAUSE");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente executar dessa forma, limpando o buffer do teclado

```
double somaT = 0, mediaM = 0, mediaT = 0, altura, somaM = 0;
double maiorH = 0, menorH = 999, maiorM = 0, menorM = 999;
char nome[30], sexo;                    
int i, mulher, turma;
turma = 0;
mulher = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    printf ("Digite seu nome: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets (nome);
    printf ("Digite seu sexo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    sexo = getche();
    printf ("\nDigite sua altura: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf ("%lf", &altura);

    if (sexo = 'm') {
            if (altura > maiorH) {
                maiorH = altura;
            }
            if (altura < menorH) {
                menorH = altura;
            }
    }
    if (sexo = 'f') {
        mulher++;
        somaM = somaM + altura;
            if (altura > maiorM) {
                    maiorM = altura;
                }
                if (altura < menorM) {
                    menorM = altura;
                }
    }
    turma++;
    somaT = somaT + altura;
}
mediaM = somaM / mulher;
mediaT = somaT / turma;

if (maiorH > maiorM) {
    printf ("A maior altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", maiorH);
}
else {
    printf ("A maior altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", maiorM);
}
if (menorH < menorM) {
    printf ("A menor altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", menorH);
}
else {
    printf ("A menor altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", menorM);
}

printf ("A media de altura das mulheres eh: %.2lf \n", mediaM);
printf ("A media de altura da turma eh: %.2lf \n", mediaT);

system ("PAUSE");
```

Comment: Pronto, resolvido. Obrigado

Comment: opa blz , da um voto ai pra nois na questão resolvida pra ajuda, vlw